# Форматирование даты MySQL DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, дата

В течении развития проекта пришлось изменить формат вывода дат записей. Модуль создания статей сохраняет дату в формате MySQL DATETIME, то есть вида 
`2016-12-28 14:22:10` Можно легко изменить формат сохранения даты, но тогда нарушится работа других php обработчиков, берущих информацию о дате из базы данных, записей в которой накопилось прилично. Мне в определенном блоке нужна запись вида `28 дек'16` и под hover `14:22:10` из `2016-12-28 14:22:10`

Вопрос: Есть ли стандартные функции php которые из строки вида `2016-12-28 14:22:10` вернут мне строку типа `28 дек'16`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, посмотрите класс [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php).
И в частности функцию [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php), там же возможные варианты форматов для вывода и для разбора строки

В общем виде это будет работать так:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
echo "в определенном блоке " . $date->format('d m Y') . "\n";
echo "и под hover " . $date->format('H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

есть. вы можете задать формат вывода даты/времени.

```
//28 дек 16`
echo $date('d M y');
```

Про формат можете почитать -
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Comment: Да нет, мне нужно вывести не текущие дату и время, а заведомо записанные в бд в виде строки.

Comment: я описывал суть. правило записанное в скобках подходит и для DateTime::createFromFormat, который вам посоветовали выше

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, мои функции, которые я написал для своего движка, помогут.

```
    function getMonthName($no)
{
    $month = '';
    if($no == '01') $month = 'января';
    elseif($no == '02') $month = 'февраля';
    elseif($no == '03') $month = 'марта';
    elseif($no == '04') $month = 'апреля';
    elseif($no == '05') $month = 'мая';
    elseif($no == '06') $month = 'июня';
    elseif($no == '07') $month = 'июля';
    elseif($no == '08') $month = 'августа';
    elseif($no == '09') $month = 'сентября';
    elseif($no == '10') $month = 'октября';
    elseif($no == '11') $month = 'ноября';
    elseif($no == '12') $month = 'декабря';
    return $month;
}
function getWordDateTime($date, $no_year = false)
{
    if($date != '')
    {
        $dtArr = explode(' ', $date);
        if(isset($dtArr[0])) {
            $arr = explode('-', $dtArr[0]);
            $ret = $arr[2] . ' ' . getMonthName($arr[1]);
            if (!$no_year) $ret .= ' ' . $arr[0];
        }
        if(isset($dtArr[1])) $ret .= $dtArr[1];
        return $ret;
    }
    else return '';
}
```